# How to print output from SQLite 3 in Python

Tags: python, printing, sqlite

Here is my code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('myfile.db')
print(conn.execute("PRAGMA table_info(mytable);"))
```

When I ran that, I got this output:

> sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02889FAO

How can I print the actual SQLite 3 output of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should to fetch results.
Here is a working example:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('myfile.db')
cursor = conn.execute("PRAGMA table_info(mytable);")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

Or with pretty print:

```
import sqlite3
from pprint import pprint

conn = sqlite3.connect('myfile.db')
cursor = conn.execute("PRAGMA table_info(mytable);")
results = cursor.fetchall()
pprint(results)
```

Comment: Something is missing in the first sentence. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53128319/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer accessing data by column names instead of by index, the provided solution will not be suitable. When fetching the output, SQLite typically returns an `sqlite3.Row` object rather than a `list`. To easily view and print this output, you'd want to convert the result to a dictionary.

Here's how you can do it:

```
import sqlite3 as sl

con = sl.connect('db.sqlite')
con.row_factory = sl.Row
rows = con.execute('SELECT * FROM table').fetchall()

for row in rows:
     print(dict(row))
     print(row['column_name'])
```